# Can I bbq with grill on top with this?

Tags: grilling, barbecue

I got this grill but as you can see it’s rusty. My question is if I put grill on top, is it safe to cook chicken on it?
[image]

Comment: This is the same grill you bought new 3 weeks ago?

Comment: Is that where the coals will go?

Comment: @moscafj yes it is. The corners r where the grill with rest.

Comment: as long as the grill is clean...see the answer by @FuzzyChef

Answer (score 1):

If the food is not touching the rusty metal, then there is no health concern.  Particularly not when the rusted metal itself is being heated to over 200C.

There may be a safety concern with using the grill, though; rusted galvanized sheet steel is not going to be strong or reliable, and the grill may fall apart, scattering hot coals.  So you only want to use it on top of a fireproof surface.

Comment: I hope it's not galvanised. [Zinc fumes aren't good](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_fume_fever), and anyway the zinc would melt in contact with hot coals (melting point 420°C, glowing coals over 600). Stainless can rust at high enough temperatures, and obviously mild steel rusts too

Comment: It is galvanized.  He posted more pics on an earlier question.  I'm pretty sure all the zinc has burned off by now, given.

Comment: Note that I don't recommend using this grill at all.  But that's not the question the OP asked.

Comment: Well, this question is effectively "is it safe to cook over this hot metal thing?", and zinc would be a reason to say "no". After all, cooking safety isn't just food safety (don't burn or cut yourself). I reckon most of the zinc has gone, but the grey on the top edge is probably still galvanised, and there may be some that melted and ran down.

Comment: Galvanised or not I wouldn't be keen, but it could be possible to cook at a sensible temperature to avoid the classic charred but raw failure. With a lot of hassle and some other bits.

Comment: And regarding your last point, it's even worse than you say. Assuming the legs hold perfectly, dry vegetation could easily touch the bottom and catch fire; even the radiant heat would damage a lot of things underneath, or ignite a few (imagine putting it on plastic table!) I have a briefcase style portable one which is a bit wobbly but OK with careful placement. Despite 3-4x longer legs, it has the same problem

Comment: I don't believe this "grill" has legs.

Comment: I thought in the picture on the other question there were some really short ones, but it's not linked from here

Comment: Anyway, it's not my experience -- based on some experiences with welding, and with cheap pizza ovens -- that zinc vapor is not a real health problem for cooking outside; there's simply not enough vapor to give you a faceful.  However, that is not an expert health recommendation, and I've done no actual testing.

Comment: That's quite possibly true, but it is a known hazard of the material, and it would be remiss of me not to mention it

Comment: @FuzzyChef Respectfully, the experiences you mentioned do not qualify one to make safety recommendations to others. You're not a properly trained welder or expert. You're just a hobbyist when it comes to galvanized steel. You mention that "there's simply not enough vapor to give you a faceful". Given that the vapor is largely odorless, it's clear that you are way out of your league in answering this question. I have formal welding training & years of experience, but I don't even consider myself qualified to answer it, except to say I wouldn't let my family eat anything cooked over that thing.

Comment: @FuzzyChef My above comment is, of course, only related to this question.  You very well could be an expert in one or more other fields that qualify you to make safety recommendations in those other fields.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket If you are an expert, then answer the question yourself.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Read my comment again. Even with formal training and much more experience, I specifically stated I still don't consider myself to be qualified.